# Is there a way for Expo applications with the managed workflow to be distributed to testers with an invite link?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

It should be as simple as possible for the testers. Best case would be a link that they can click on that directly installs the app on iOS and Android devices (maybe through another app similar to testflight). As we're using Firebase in our application I looked at Firebase App distribution but it seems that it doesn't work with the managed workflow of Expo. We would need to eject our app to (possibly) make it work. As we have only a limited amount of time until the test I would like to avoid a lenghty evaluation process like the one testflight requires.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I came across diawi.com which seems to offer what I'm searching for. It's really easy for the testers, they just have to scan a qr code or click on a link and the app actually appears as a standalone application.

Answer (score 2):

Apps using Managed Workflow can be shared via Expo Go: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/sharing-preview-releases/

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, thank you! As far as I understood every tester would need to have an Expo account though, right? In our use case that would sadly be too much effort for the testers because we want to make it as simple as possible for the tester to check how many people would download the app.